# how to load a webview before showing the panel?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, android-webview

Ive got two panels. The first panel contains a button and when i press that button, the next panel with a webview appears. Is there any way to load the webview first before showing the panel where it is located?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, set the WebView's visibility to invisible with myWebView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); and then when you receive the callback the page has loaded set the visibility back to VISIBLE.

Comment: it is still the same with waiting for it to load...

What I want is while I'm in the first panel, the webview in the second will start loading so that when the second panel appears, the webview is already loaded.

Comment: What are these panels you speak of?

Comment: Login.xml has button1 that when you press it shows Main.xml. Main.xml has a webview. I want the program to load the webview first before showing Main.xml. So that when Main.xml appears, the webview is already loaded.